# Custom Logout in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: 2010, 2007, login

I have sp application where there are 15 subsite.I need to redirect each subsite to the respective logout page when i click logout.How do i achieve this & properly logout each respective subsite?

Answer (score 1):

No need to LOGOUT each SubSite but simple call this page in the _layouts virtual folder (available from wherever in SharePoint) use

(the / in front would make your link relative to your site collection)
/_layouts/signOut.aspx

Comment: i have custom pages created for each subsite logout.I used powershell to set my custom application page as signout page.i am now able to redirect the logout url but the problem is i am not successfully logging out the user>ADFS authentication is being used by me

Comment: C:\PS>Set-SPCustomLayoutsPage -Identity “_layouts/signout.aspx” -Relat ivePath “/_layouts/custompages/mysignout.aspx” -WebApplication “http:/ /server_name/mywebapp”

Comment: I'm a little confused about your definition of subSite as custom login pages are set Web Application wide. On the other hand ADFS issues an STS-specific cookie (MSISSignOut) to performed logout across all relying parties, which is Session Based (close browser and you loose it), but NOT lost by navigating simply to SignOUt page - need to close or remove it manually.

Comment: well i created a application page where i wrote javascript to "clearauthenticationcache" . logout works fine in IE but mozilla and firefox i cannot successfully logout.

Comment: could you explain how to remove the session manually ?

Comment: If you used FBA you could use this http://jasear.wordpress.com/2011/01/10/sharepoint-2010-set-session-timout-on-a-fba-enabled-site/